# Should the Staging and Production Docker images be the same in Nuxt.js App?

Tags: docker, nuxt.js

I am developing application Nuxt.js (SPA mode) on the docker, and I am considering hot to deploy nuxt application to staging and production environment.

According to Docker's style, staging and production should be used the same image, but Nuxt.js embeds env at build time, so it needs to be built with staging and production every time.

If you have any best practices on whether Nuxt production deployments should be built every time they are deployed, or whether it is better to use a common image of staing, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> According to Docker's style, staging and production should be used the
>   same image, but Nuxt.js embeds env at build time, so it needs to be
>   built with staging and production every time.

Short answer NO.

.env file should be ingnored in git and fill by secrets in your CI before build with docker or manually write on your production enviroment.

You can be use two .env files either:

- .env
- .env.prod

Add this at the top of your nuxt.config.js file.

```js
const fs = require('fs'),
path = require('path');

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && fs.existsSync('.env.prod')){
  require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, `.env.prod`)});
} else{
  require('dotenv').config();
}
```